# SSRS Report joining data sets in BID 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

How can we join to Data sets in SSRS? For example we have Dataset1 and Dataset2 and the common columns between them are c1 and c2. I know we can use lookup, but wondering if there is a shortcut like using variables to do that based on your experience?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I am afraid that this is not possible in 2008. You can workaround it though by implementing the logic in the dataset itself or you can create sub-reports to achieve what you are after.

However, if you have the ability to use a 2008R2 instance you can indeed do what you are asking by using the Lookup functions. Here is more information on it:

**LOOKUP:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx

**LOOKUPSET:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

If the common column(s) between two data sets are going to be used as the report parameters, then joing the data sets are automatically maintained via parameter. In my case, the common columns were in fact the reports parameters , so by assigning these parameters to each data set definition individually, the link between the data sets are created. Simple!

However if it is not the case, we should use Lookup function as Mr Bronstone mentioned above perfectly.